# Mongo consider October 1st and 2nd are different months

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, nosql, nestjs

I need to get all records for a month, for example, I created the following two records:

- October 1, 2020 (2020-**09**-30T21:00:00.000+00:00)
- October 5, 2020 (2020-**10**-04T21:00:00.000+00:00)

[Example entries in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Ovu.png)

Due to storage with an hour offset, we see that they belong to different months, but when converted to Date (JavaScript), we will get the correct date (01/10/2020 and 05/10/2020).

But Mongo **counts these two fields for different months and I only get one record.**

Example of query:

```
.aggregate([
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        month: {$month: '$date'},
                    },
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        month: Number(month),
                    },
                },
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save a date to Mongo you might have noticed it is saved as an `ISODate` and not a `Date` type. First let's understand what is `ISODate`, `ISODate()` is a wrapper function that converts all date's to a single representation that's easy for Mongo to handle. as specified in their [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/model-time-data/#overview):

> MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and will convert any local time representations into this form.

Now you are not in `UTC` timezone, how do I know it? because your "right" time is not the `UTC` represented time.

So why when you convert it in javascript you get the "right" time? Well again there are many methods and different ways to convert a `Date` object into a string depending on timezone. But javascript uses your machine time (which I guess is synced to your timezone) to do the conversion.

So what can you do? You need to adjust the aggregation for your timezone gap, assuming all records come from the same timezone you can do this:

- (let's assume you're 5 hours ahead of `UTC` for this case, so we'll want to add 1000 * 60 * 60 * 5 = 18000000 milliseconds to the Mongo date)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            month: {
                $month: {
                    $add: [
                        "$date",
                        18000000 // 5 hours in milliseconds
                    ]
                },
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            month: Number(month)
        }
    }
]);
```

If you're gathering documents from different timezone's then you'll want to save an `offset` field as your saving the time into the database to help with the calculations.